# Cannot copy text from PDF generated with Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, pdf

I exported my document as PDF from Google Drive on the Web. When I try to Copy/Paste my content, I get this :

Text is in *French*. I can *visualize* it with no difficulties. The font is *Verdana*. There is only *two colors* on the document. It is an *A4* doc. There are *471* words. It does contain a profile *photo*.

I am trying to *copy/view* using `Preview` on `Mac OS X Mountain Lion`.

Please do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Any idea whet the original text said? What language was used? That looks like some form of multi-byte encoding scheme.

Comment: Text is in french if this answer you're question. I can visualize the PDF everywhere, but copying does not work well. I don't know how to get the encoding scheme ?

Comment: Neither do I, I was hoping the language would give us a clue. Sorry!

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the document *source* is. Is it a Google Apps document that has been saved in PDF format, or a PDF generated from another source that was uploaded to Google Drive?

Comment: Also, what OS are you using, where are you pasting to?

Comment: hi @Fuhrmanator It is a google document that was exported in PDF format. I am running Mac OS X Moutain Lion.

Comment: What PDF application are you copying it from (Adobe Reader, Chrome's PDF viewer, etc)? Please add all those things to the question. I just made a French Google Apps document with some accented characters and exported it to PDF. The PDF was opened in Adobe Reader and I copied and pasted it into Word 2010. The text appears normally. Also, if you can share the PDF with us, we can perhaps test it.

Comment: I will add more infos ... I can't share the document with you, it is confidential. I am trying to copy/view using `Preview` on `Mac OS X Moutain-Lion`.

Comment: @ALJIMohamed here's what I get when I paste the first line: (using Chrome's preview) `,QJpQLHXUeWXGHVHW'pYHORSSHPHQW` (using Adobe PDF) ``. The PDF properties (in Adobe) say your PDF was produced by the application "Documill Publishor 6.3.12 by Documill" -- I just generated a PDF with drive.google.com and got the same properties, however accented characters are OK. The problem in your document seems to be the [embedded fonts with custom encoding](http://superuser.com/q/119393/128228).  Can you try changing the font in Google?

Comment: @ALJIMohamed I can now copy/paste the first line that's legible. I've updated my answer below. I'm curious what font you chose before? It would be great if you could reproduce the problem in a Google Apps document that you can share with everyone.

Comment: I would love too but It is a little bit late. Anyway , thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some PDF documents (especially with accented characters) get strange encoding. You can see this when you inspect the properties of the PDF file (e.g. in Acrobat). For more information, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/119393/search-pdfs-with-non-standard-character-encodings).

- One solution is to try another font in your source document that uses standard encodings.
- Another solution (I've seen in Windows) is to print the PDF document to CutePDF (effectively re-saving it as PDF).